# ng-repeat for multiple `<tr>` elements AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to iterate through an array of object inside `<tbody>` with `<tr np-repeat>` but given the circumstances and the codebase I have right now, I am having trouble basically conditionally rendering certain `<tr>`s based on some key-value pairs in the corresponding objects. A custom wrapper directive such as ng-container to wrap around the `<tr>`s would be helpful in this situation but I am fairly new to Angular.js so if anyone has some reference to an existing solution I'd rather inspiring myself from it than creating my own. Thank you!

I have tried using ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end but again it does not fit into my situation because it only specifies where repeat ends whereas I need to also specify where repeat ends. Creating a directive with transclude is probably the way to go as per what I found so far but I am not exactly sure how.

Controller stuff

```
$scope.array = [{show: true}, {key: value}, {key: value}]
```

Template stuff

```html
<tbody>
  <custom-ng-container-directive ng-repeat="element in array">
    <tr ng-if="element.show">
      <td>some text</td>
      <td>more text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="!element.show">
      <td>{{ element.key }}</td>
      <td>other text</td>
    </tr>
  </custom-ng-container-directive>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Multiple `<tbody>` elements are perfectly valid HTML so you could move your `ng-repeat` up to the `<tbody>` element. I'm not sure what issues you had `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` - it's not clear from your question.

Comment: @georgeawg Firstly I don't know if it is necessary in my case to actually use such a directive. Secondly, I just feel like it is mentioned in many Stackoverflow posts that many directives are somehow not in the Angular.js documentation.

Comment: @Lex There is some existing JQuery that manipulate the template that sort of looks into only one ``<tbody>`` so having multiple of them is causing problems for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` for this. Note that you are missing `<td></td>` elements and placing text directly in a `<tr></tr>` is not well formed HTML.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="element in array" ng-if="element.show">
        some text
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="!element.show">
      {{ element.key }}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put in ``<td>``s. Basically the amount of ``<td>``s and the content inside need to differ based on key-value pairs in each object

Comment: I went with using repeat on ``<tbody>`` and it is working in my case for now. I will try to create an Angular.js version of ng-container later on if needed. I just think it is super useful also when you want to avoid that extra ``<div></div>``. Thank you @Lex